# Rails error: instance method already defined by another enum but there are no repeats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I am trying to debug some errors that appear when I run `bundle exec rake`  tasks.

```
ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "catalogue" on the model "CollectionContext", but this will generate a instance method "museum?", which is already defined by another enum.
```

There are a number of questions on SO relating to this problem but all seem to come down to the use of the same value for different enums within the same model, which can be resolved with the use of _suffix or _prefix.

Here's an excellent explanation of enum usage in Rails https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum

In my case I cannot see a duplicate in my model. How can I debug the error further?

```
class CollectionContext < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Authority::Abilities
  self.authorizer_name = 'ManagedContentAuthorizer'

  has_many :context_sets, inverse_of: :collection_context
  has_many :museum_collections, through: :context_sets,
                                source: :contextable,
                                source_type: 'MuseumCollection'

  enum catalogue: %i[museum archive library]
  enum vocabulary: {category: 10,
                    collection: 20,
                    concept: 30,
                    event: 40,
                    gallery: 50,
                    material: 60,
                    organisation: 70,
                    people: 80,
                    person: 90,
                    place: 100,
                    style: 110,
                    technique: 120}

  validate :check_multiple

  def check_multiple
    if [identifier, query, query_url].compact.count != 1
      errors[:base] << " cannot set multiple context links"
    end
  end
end
```

I've now discovered that if I run rake with my rails environment set to TEST, it doesn't show any problems in the console. So it is a development only problem. I have experimented with my gemfile and put all dev only gems into the dev and test group but I still get the error when running rake in dev.

This is my config/development.rb file

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.configure do
  config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '10.xxxx'
end
```

Comment: Remove temporarily the `museum` enum, try with `CollectionContext.method(: museum?).source_location`. That should tell you where that method is defined, if it is.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. With that command I get: `undefined method museum?' for class '#...'`

Comment: Interesting, do you have a way to replicate this problem? Maybe a small repo.

Comment: I'm working on a rather large legacy codebase so I imagine it would be extremely hard to replicate on a small scale.

Comment: Got it. Try globally looking where else `museum` is defined. What's in the `Authority::Abilities` file?

Comment: Not sure about Authority::Abilities is that in the authority.rb file, perhaps this is the section? `  # ABILITIES
  # =========
  # Teach Authority how to understand the verbs and adjectives in your system.
  # Perhaps you need {:microwave => 'microwavable'}. I'm not saying you do, of
  # course. Stop looking at me like that.
  #
  # Defaults are as follows:
  #
  # config.abilities =  {
  #   :create => 'creatable',
  #   :read   => 'readable',
  #   :update => 'updatable',
  #   :delete => 'deletable'
  # }`

Comment: I also tried the _suffix trick with `enum catalogue: %i[museum library], _suffix: true` but I get the same error `ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "catalogue" on the model "CollectionContext", but this will generate a instance method "museum_catalogue?", which is already defined by another enum` Which makes me wonder if this issue is relevant.https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20643 Could I be loading the model somewhere else?

Comment: I am also facing same issue & there is no duplication in enum values in my codebase too. Did you find any solution for it? @whatapalaver

Comment: No I'm afraid not...

Comment: @whatapalaver which version of Rails are you using? I encountered this in 5.1.7 and I'm pretty sure this is Rails bug, although I'm not yet sure what causes it and what's the solution. Knowing your version would help to narrow the problem down.

Comment: Hi @katafrakt I'n using Rails 5.2.2.1

Comment: @whatapalaver My problem turned out to be caused by defining enum within ActiveSupport.on_load block, which was called every time autoreload in dev kicked in (so, basically, on each request). But in your case it seems to be something else unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Probably related to having spring or some other such thing running.  Try starting dev with DISABLE_SPRING=1 or just removing spring.

Other possibilities include there is a boolean column named `museum` which is where the `museum?` method is coming from and some other code we don't see.

In terms of debugging, I'd just open up Rails where the stacktrace is point to the error being raised and use introspection there to see where the detected existing method is defined?  sure, there are other tools in the toolbelt like method_added and tracepoint, but I like the 'find where it's raised and do `method(:museum?).source_location` or some such.

To avoid re-evaluating an enum line in my Rails apps I often will define it for example like

```rb
  enum catalogue: %i[museum archive library] unless method_defined?(:museum?)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I did `bin/spring stop` and then restarted my server. The error disappeared. Rails 7.0.3.4, Ruby 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I just found myself having this problem too. Frustratingly, it seemed to be caused by a syntax problem elsewhere in the model - specifically a `delegate`. As soon as I fixed that, without touching anything else, it sorted itself out.

Try removing the enum definition altogether and then attempting to build an instance of the model. Fix any errors that appear, and then re-instate the enum definition. May not help in your particular situation as I can't spot any obvious errors in the model code you provided, but may help someone else who stumbles across this issue.